# app freezing when images loading in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this array:

```
media = [  
        [UIImage(named: "1.png")!,UIImage(named: "14.png")!,UIImage(named: "2.png")!],
        [UIImage(named: "3.png")!,UIImage(named: "15.png")!,UIImage(named: "4.png")!],
        [UIImage(named: "5.png")!,UIImage(named: "16.png")!,UIImage(named: "6.png")!],
        [UIImage(named: "7.png")!,UIImage(named: "17.png")!,UIImage(named: "8.png")!],
        [UIImage(named: "9.png")!,UIImage(named: "18.png")!,UIImage(named: "10.png")!],
        [UIImage(named: "11.png")!,UIImage(named: "19.png")!,UIImage(named: "12.png")!],
        [UIImage(named: "13.png")!,UIImage(named: "21.png")!,UIImage(named: "47.png")!]
    ]
```

Also I have a `collectionView`:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return media.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return media[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

        cell.thisImage.image = media[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

But I have a problem. When I scroll my `collectionView` my app freezing. But when I scroll for all section and continue scroll next. My app not freezing.

How to fix it?

Comment: How large are your images?

Comment: @particleman about 1mb

Comment: Check your memory usage in Instruments, but it's advisable to downscale the images unless you're displaying them at full resolution. It takes time to decode the PNG, so if you're doing the loading on the main thread, you're likely to see a slowdown. Again, Instruments is the best way to see what's taking all the time.

Comment: @particleman Maybe somehow load images in advance? I need to use this image.

Comment: Preloading the image can help if you're CPU constrained. But it's best not to optimize before you know the source of the problem. Instruments will allow you to measure your resource usage so that you can both _identify_ the problem and _verify_ that any change you make actually improves the performance.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage ? it caches your images so your app will be smooth

Comment: @AriePinto I use this `cell.thisImage.sd_setImage(with:UIImage(named: imageName), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))` and this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'URL?'` How to fix it?

Comment: well if you want a local image just use "cell.thisImage.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")", the SDWebImage Lib was made for images from links so you can use it like this "sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "imageName"))"

Comment: @AriePinto What is `gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png`?

Comment: Just an image url example my friend

Comment: @AriePinto But I need load image from project.

Comment: So you don’t need this lib my friend, your peoblem llies within another place, if i could share more code or the whole project ill be happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better image loading on TableView/CollectionView cell [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is perfect image loading library. Add this to your project and use for loading image on collectionView. It will remove the UI freezing issue during image load.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

        cell.thisImage.sd_setImage(with:Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(indexPath.row + 1)", withExtension:"png"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

        return cell
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'URL?'

Comment: Are the images in a directory or asset category?

Comment: asset category. Or in project navigator with other swift file.

Comment: I use this code `let imageName = media1[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.cardImageView.sd_setImage(with:Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(imageName)", withExtension:"png"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))` Where `media1 ` just string numerals. Works well. What is `placeholder.png`?

Comment: placeholder is an image. If the image is not loading then placeholder images shown. In your case placeholder image not needed. You can remove this or set nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving only the name of the images in your array like

```
media = [
    ["1.png","14.png","2.png"],
    ["3.png","15.png","4.png"], 
   // Rest of the image names here.
   ]
]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

        let imageName = media[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        //cell.thisImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        cell.thisImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName, in: nil, compatibleWith: nil)
        return cell
}
```

Try and share the result.

Comment: In this case I have same images in all section

Comment: In section I have 3 cells. return media[section].count

Comment: Freezing. I not use `SDWebImage `. If I use `SDWebImage ` I get `Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'URL?'`

Comment: Try with this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624154-imagenamed?language=objc

Comment: Checkout my edits and share the results. I found that was discussed on this thread for iOS 9, but thought of giving it a try https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17888

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177593/discussion-between-bhavin-kansagara-and-user).

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your 'media' array is in sectioned or not. As you have shown how you have allocated your 'media' array, is just a single image array. Also, you are trying to get image name from a sectioned array which is the cause of the crash.

So, better to use 'media' array directly without any section or if in case you want to access it as a sectioned array, then allocate 'media' array as a sectioned array.